# PostgreSQL says 'symbol not found' when I try to use PQnfelds

Tags: c, postgresql, libpq

I wrote a C function to be executed from within PostgreSQL (with a `CREATE FUNCTION ... LANGUAGE C;` command) but when I do so, it responds 'PQnfields: symbol not found'.
I tried to include the path to where the libpq library is when I compile, like this:

```
 gcc -lpq -fpic -c crossdb.c -I`pg_config --includedir-server` -I /usr/include/ -std=c99
```

But it didn't work. 
I think that it is simply not possible to use libpq to query the database from a function... So if you know how to do it or what is causing this error message, I'd be happy to ear it from you.

Comment: libpq is for frontend-programs. Your function will become part of the DBMS backend, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-c.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to put the directory containing `libpq.so.*` on PostgreSQL's shared library path, either by setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the server's environment or by adding `-Wl,-rpath,/path/to/so` to the compile line.

Are you using the PGXS framework to build the shared library? That gives you most of the proper flags automatically.

Look at `postgres_fdw`'s `Makefile` for inspiration, it links with `libpq` too.

Taking a step back: are you sure that you need a function called `crossdb` that calls the client? I would investigate if a foreign table or `dblink` can do what you are trying to achieve.